# mocking a file within a function

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, unit-testing, mocking

I have written the following function :

```
def get_env_id(id):
    with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'srm.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        return data.get(id)
```

I am performing unit test on the above function. I want to mock the file within the function with some json file. The json file content is  as follows:

```
{"id":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},"value":{"0":20,"1":30,"2":40}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) from unnitest package, something like:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

BASE_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

MOCK_DATA = {"id": {"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3}, "value": {"0": 20, "1": 30, "2": 40}}


def get_env_id(id):
    with open(BASE_PATH / 'srm.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        return data.get(id)


@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data=json.dumps(MOCK_DATA))
def test_get_env_id(mock_file):
    id = get_env_id("id")
    assert id == {"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3}
    mock_file.assert_called_once()
    mock_file.assert_called_with(BASE_PATH / 'srm.json')
```